# Jquery plugin with google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a webpage in jquery mobile and now I am using the plugin "fullCalendar" for showing info from a google calendar.

I was asked about use another plugin instead of this one to be able of showing the day square in other color rather than shows the event title and hour.

I searched on internet but I haven't found any plugin for doing what I want.

Do you know one with this ability?

Comment: if it's only color you're worried about, why not just change the CSS?

Comment: I don't want to show the event name, just change the color of that day. But I need one which parse the google calendar events

Answer (score 2):

User [`eventRender`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback to modify how the event is rendered (no text, different colour, anything else you need).

Comment: Can you give me an example about this?